# How to get from and to dates in android Date picker

Tags: java, daterangepicker

I am using [MaterialDatePicker](https://material.io/components/date-pickers/android) from material.io. I am able to create date picker and add a function  addOnPositiveButtonClickListener, when the date is picked. What I want to do in the function is to get from and to dates picked in datepicker.

But the onPositiveButtonClick has only one argument  `selection` which is an Object,  on Logging it using tostring or debugging  I can see the `selection` object is a pair with 2 numbers. Which I assume is timestamp of from and to dates. But I am not able to use the `selection` pair to get these values seperately.

```
dateRangePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                Log.i("selection",selection.toString()); // this prints """ selection "Pair{1655251200000 1657756800000}"  """
                //selection.getKey() this function does not exist on the pair selection however

            }
```

Can someone help on how to get the from and to dates out of selection(pair/Object) without slicing and dicing the string from toString()

Answer (score 2):

You can override `onPositiveButtonClick` method like this:

```
 @Override public void onPositiveButtonClick(Pair<Long,Long> selection) {
           Long startDate = selection.first;
           Long endDate = selection.second;
           //Do something...
      }
```